# PyQt overlay fade in/out with animation framework

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have been working on a school project that involves a Qt/PyQt GUI. I am currently trying to get a specific menu to overlay the main window. I would love to add a sort of fading transition when toggled, but I can't seem to find many solid examples. There also seems to be a lack of python documentation in this area. If someone could provide me with some functional code, that would be great!

Heres what I have found so far, overlay:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import time
import threading

class overlay(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(overlay, self).__init__(parent)

        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QPushButton("Hello world!")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.percent = 0


class windowOverlay(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(windowOverlay, self).__init__(parent)

        self.editor = QTextEdit()
        self.editor.setPlainText("OVERLAY"*100)

        self.button = QPushButton("Toggle Overlay")

        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.editor)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.overlay = overlay(self.editor)
        self.overlay.hide()

        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.overlay.setVisible(False) if self.overlay.isVisible() else self.overlay.setVisible(True))

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.overlay.resize(event.size())
        event.accept()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = windowOverlay()
    main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```